# Android - Out of memory while loading bitmaps

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, bitmap

I have 3 activities, while I switch from 2 to 3, my app like restarts and jumps to 1.

I drag bitmap from activity to another one.

What to do? What trick shoul i use less memory?

```
02-02 06:29:20.017    1509-1509/marty.martzero D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 508K, 6% free 21312K/22663K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
02-02 06:29:20.027    1509-1509/marty.martzero E/io﹕ bitmaptosave = xz
02-02 06:29:20.586    1526-1526/marty.martzero D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 69K, 4% free 8003K/8259K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
02-02 06:29:20.606    1526-1526/marty.martzero I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 10.228MB for 2479056-byte allocation
02-02 06:29:20.656    1526-1528/marty.martzero D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 10424K/10695K, paused 15ms+10ms, total 54ms
02-02 06:29:20.857    1526-1528/marty.martzero D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 11189K/11335K, paused 16ms+3ms, total 56ms
02-02 06:29:20.937    1526-1526/marty.martzero D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
02-02 06:29:20.947    1526-1526/marty.martzero D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a0fcf60, tid 1526
```

Comment: please post your code for loading bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, know that Bitmaps are evil in mobile applications. They occupy big chunk of RAM if they are not used efficiently. Following methods might help for a better memory management:

- Use a singleton to hold on to your bitmaps.
- However, be very careful about memory leak in android, see [this](http://www.curious-creature.com/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/comment-page-1/).
- DO NOT recreate a bitmap which has already been loaded to the memory. For example do not recreate a scaled version of Bitmap while you still hold a reference to the original version of a bitmap. If you need different sizes of a single bitmap, use matrix manipulation, rather than resizing the Bitmap itself each time.

Do this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, dstRec1, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, dstRec2, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, dstRec3, null);
```

And NOT this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap1,  left1, top1, null);
canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap2,  left2, top2, null);
canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap3,  left3, top3, null);
```

where bitmap1, bitmap2, and bitmap3 are the same file only with different scaling.

- Try to load bitmap as small size as you can. Read more details about sampling [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).
- Finally, if your application really really needs a big heap size, you can request a bigger heap through setting up a flag in your manifest, application section:

  android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: You'e welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted if this was what you were looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your bitmap public and static, and use it in another activity. There is no need to drag with activity.

And another way to compress bitmap to reduce memory size

```
BitmapFactory.Option imageOpts = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
imageOpts.inSampleSize = 2;   // for 1/2 the image to be loaded
Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, imageOpts), 96, 96, false);
```